# Disable Maybe checking in Flow Type

Tags: flowtype

Is there a way to completely and globally disable Maybe checking in Flow type? Suppose the following simplified scenario when I load a user to Redux state, it is `null` in initial state but it is always present after the application is initialized and a user is loaded. It is annoying to always check if something exists when it always exists.

```
type User = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
}

type State = {
  user?: User
}
```

The error is reported here:

```
function getUser(state: State): string {
   return state.user.name // <-- Flow: Cannot get `state.user.name` because property `name` is missing in undefined [1].
}
```

Solution 1 - use `$FlowFixMe` but it could hide some real issue

```
function getUser(state: State): string {
  // $FlowFixMe
  return state.user.name
}
```

Solution 2 - make some assertion, but it's too boilerplate and works only with literal checks, does not work with utility functions like `_.isEmpty`

```
function getUser(state: State): string {
  if (state.user) {
    return state.user.name
  } else {
    return ''
  }
}
```

Solution 3 (I like the most) - declare that some property exists and add `$FlowFixMe` to initialization instead of getter:

```
type User = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
}

type State = {
  user: User
}

const initialState: State = {
  // $FlowFixMe
  user: null,
}
```

Solution 4 (I like the least) - declare that some property exists and initialize it with some mock data:

```
type User = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
}

type State = {
  user: User
}

const initialState: State = {
  user: {
    name: '',
    age: 0,
  },
}
```

But all four solutions are just workarounds. I want to simply disable all null checking in Flow. Is it possible or some better solution exists?

Comment: It feels like you'd be better off showing an example of the component itself, and asking for approaches to structuring it that might avoid constant repeated assertions.

Comment: Constant repeated assertions are because of Flow type otherwise it show an error. In the most cases it occurs in legacy projects where we added Flow. It worked perfectly and now we need to add these extra assertions or `// $FlowFixMe`.

Comment: Adding Flow may well require some amount of refactoring or additional assertions. It is up to you to prove to Flow that your code is typesafe, and there is no guarantee that existing code will do that.